# Does AS/400 Login attempt reset?

Tags: iseries, ibm-data-studio

I'm currently trying to log into a remote AS/400 server. I was given credentials to obtain some data and do a couple tests. After 2 failed attempts, the iAccess Client showed me an alert saying my user would be blocked if the third attempt failed, so I stopped trying.

I'm reporting the event, but I need to know if the "attempt counter" resets after some time.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically reset AFTER a successful login is made.